# How to derive the standard error of product of two variables with unequal sample sizes?

Tags: variance, standard-error, delta-method

Say $H$=height, $b$=angle, and $d$=distance; $H=\text{tan}(b)*d$.

- $b$ has a sample size of $5$ with mean $40.4166$ degrees and variance $3.75E-05$.
- $d$ has a sample size of $3$ with mean $124.3$ and variance $0.01$.

Could you explain why $$\text{tan}(b)^2*\text{var}(H)+(H*\sec(b)^2)^2*\text{var}(b)=\text{var}(\text{tan}(b)*d)?$$ I understand using variance properties the first part but not the "$\sec(b)^2$" part. Finally, how does one get from the $\text{var}(\text{tan}(b)*d)$ to the standard error of the estimation of $H$? I know standard error=stdev/sqrt(sample size) but I don't know what to do with multiple variables.

Comment: Thanks! that makes a ton of sense now! Any idea about the standard error for height now and why this formula for variance would be relevant to the standard error?

Answer (score 1):

In general for a function of 2 variables f(x,y),

$$Var(f) \approx (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2Var(x)+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^2Var(y)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}Covar(x,y)$$.
Your formula is just an expression after evaluating the partial derivatives, but note that it has to be assumed that b and d are independent, since the 2 equations are equal only if the covariance is zero.

Comment: I changed to $\approx$, since this is a linear approximation. But, in this case the variances are small,. so that should be close to equal! You could test it with simulations.

Comment: You might also want to comment on the (several) errors in the original post--they need correcting.